# Knockout Binding not working after async partial view load

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, typescript

I have a requirement in my MVC 5 (KnockoutJS and TypeScript) application in which I have to load some partial views using ajax when user change tabs.

The main page has a view model which will later, when user changes tabs should handle the partial view's binding.

The problem is when I load the partial views it seems that the binding will not work.

These are the function I use to load the partial view and apply bindings in the page ViewModel class:

```
class ExportViewModel
{
public isBusy: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;

private viewCache: { [key: string]: any } = {};

constructor()
{
    this.isBusy = ko.observable(true);
    this.getView('someId');
}

private showView(view: any): void
{
    var viewContent = $('#view-content');
    viewContent.html(view);
    ko.applyBindings(this, viewContent[0]);
    this.isBusy(false);
}

private getView(someId: string): void
{
    this.isBusy(true);
    var viewContent = document.getElementById('view-content');
    ko.cleanNode(viewContent);

    var viewName = someId;
    var view = this.viewCache[viewName];
    if(view)
        this.showView(view);

    jQuery.get(`BaseUrl/${viewName}`).done((data: any) =>
    {
        this.viewCache[viewName] = data;
        this.showView(data);
    });
}
```

}

A sample partial view is like this:

```
    <div class="panel-body">
    @using( Html.BeginForm() )
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p>
                    Sample Partial View
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input data-bind="textInput: isBusy"/>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    </div>
```

In my case the input text is the content of the isBusy observable function not the true or false and also if I change the input binding to "textInput: isBusy()" then the value is **true** which is wrong because right after applyBinding I have set it to false.

Comment: Can you once confirm if showView method is being called? 
Also check what 'this' refers to in showView method

Comment: showView will get called because if I remove applyBinding nothing works at all (not even the function body will get displayed in the input). Also I believe that the 'this' should refer to the vm class instance not the function itself.

Comment: Is there somepart of code that we are missing? I am not seeing isBusy = ko.observable();

Comment: I've posted the vm class partially. I will update the post to include full VM class. Also this behavior is for all other VM's observables not just the isBusy.

Comment: Which version of knockout.js are you using?  The `textInput` binding was only added in 3.2.0

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but I changed the showView function to the following and everything worked.

```
private showView(view: any): void
{
    var viewContent = document.getElementById('view-content');
    viewContent.innerHTML = view;
    ko.applyBindings(this, viewContent);
    this.isBusy(false);
}
```